# How is this recursion for horizontally convex polyominoes clear according to author?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions, recursive-algorithms

[image]

How is the recursion $a(m,n)$ clear? I don't understand how this is *clear*.

Comment: $l$ is the number of squares in the next to bottom layer. Given a single layer of $m$ squares and a block with $l$ squares at its bottom, there are $m + l - 1$ ways to glue that layer to the bottom of the block.

Comment: @achillehui Basically $m+l-1$ ways to put the layer of $l$ blocks on top of the $m$ layer block?

Comment: Remember the constraint "Two consecutive layers meet along the edges of a number of squares". Just try arranging a block with $2$ squares on top of another layer of $2$ squares, you will see there are 3 ways to satisfy the constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As noted by achille hui in a comment, $l$ is the number of squares in the layer next to the bottom layer. The polyomino without the bottom layer contains $n-m$ squares and can thus take $a(l,n-m)$ forms, and it can be placed in $m+l-1$ different horizontal locations such that the $m$ squares in the bottom layer and the $l$ squares in the next layer overlap in at least one square.