# What's the standard term for a (connected?) plane set whose intersection with any horizontal line is either empty or an interval?

Tags: geometry, terminology

What is the term for a (connected?) set $S$ of the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that the intersection of $S$ with every horizontal line $\ell_{b}: y=b$ is either empty, or an interval of the line $\ell_b$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From where I’m from, such a set is called *$y$-simple domain* or *$y$-normal domain*.

Comment: Thanks! The term _$y$-simple domain_ seems to be pretty standard, e.g. Krantz uses it in his book "How to teach mathematics".

Answer (score 2):

Such a set is called *horizontally convex*.

Comment: For an example of this usage, see the question ["How is this recursion for horizontally convex polyominoes clear according to author?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1711179/409), which quotes a passage from a textbook in combinatorics.

Comment: @Rob Pratt: Appreciated.